# A coherent-sheaf is locally free when restricted on an open dense subset, if it is globally locally free.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$X$ is a algebraic variety. $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf. 
$U\subset X$ is an open dense subset. $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is locally free on $U$.

Can we conclude that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free on $X$ ?

Comment: It's worth noting that for any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on an integral scheme X of finite type over a field, there exists a dense open subset $U\subseteq X$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is locally free.  All you need to show this is that being locally free is an open condition (see Hartshorne exercises in section II.5) and then notice $\mathcal{F}$ is free at the generic point.

Answer (score 6):

No.
Take $X=\mathbb A^2_k\:$ and for $\mathcal F\subset \mathcal O_X$ take the ideal sheaf  of  some rational point $P\in X$.
If  $U$ is the open dense subset $U=X\setminus \{P\}\subset X$, then $\mathcal F\vert U=\mathcal O_U$ is free of rank one.
Nevertheless $\mathcal F$ is not locally free because its stalk $\mathcal F_P$ is not free as an $\mathcal O_P$-module.

**Edit: proof of non-freeness of $\mathcal F_P$**
Say  $P=(0,0)$ Then $\mathcal O_P=k[X,Y]_{\langle X,Y\rangle }$ and  the stalk $\mathcal F_P$ is the maximal ideal $\mathcal F_P=\langle X,Y\rangle \mathcal O_P\subset \mathcal O_P$.
Since $\mathcal O_P$ is of dimension $2$ its maximal ideal is of height $2$ and thus cannot be generated by a single element (Krull). Hence $\mathcal F_P$ is a non-principal ideal and is thus not free as an $\mathcal O_P$-module.

Comment: Can you please say why the stalk is not free over the local ring ?

Comment: Oh, I think I know, you can cross multiply the generators to get a relation.

Comment: Dear @Rene, I have added a proof of non-freeness in an Edit.

Comment: Thanks, is it also valid to argue by coherence, that $(x,y)$ is not a free $k[x,y]$ module ?

Comment: Dear @Rene, I'm not sure what you mean: the sheaf $\mathcal F$ is certainly coherent, and yet not locally free. Another route is to prove that $\mathcal F_P$ is not $\mathcal O_P$-flat. Another yet is to invoke that over $\mathbb A^2$ locally free sheaves are free etc.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was to ask if locally free implied that $M$ would be a free $A$ module, at least for coherent sheaves over an affine scheme.

Comment: Yes, your last option seems to indicate that.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Locally free as a coherent sheaf implies that the associated module is f.g. and projective, not necessarily free.  (A famous conjecture of Serre, proved by Quillen and Suslin, says that over *affine space*, i.e. the case when $A = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, projective implies free.  But this is a special property of affine spaces, and is not true for more general affine varieties/schemes.)

Comment: @tracing Thank-you very much for that.

Comment: Short note on the geometric picture here: The ideal sheaf of a closed subscheme is always free on the open complement (which is dense if the ambient scheme is irreducible). It is locally free if and only if the closed subscheme is a divisor, i.e. of codimension $1$.

Comment: Thank You all for the answer and discussions !